# Does brain consist of 20% Omega-3 fatty acid?

Tags: neurology

I read an article on a website about preparing for exams, and it stated that because the brain consists of 1/5 Omega-3 fatty acids, it is important to eat fish, so your brain will get better at communicating.

Being very skeptic about the statement I tried to search the Internet for more information on the topic, but I was unable to get a clear answer.

Is it really true that the human brain consists of that much fatty acid, and if yes, is all of it Omega-3?

Comment: Please link to the web-site, so we can see the claim. I haven't heard this one before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The brain doesn't have 20% lipids of any kind](http://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/facts.html). So no, it's not true.

Comment: If you discount water, it contains nearly 50% lipids.

Comment: @Adam, I agree, but that isn't what he asked. I can't tell if it's what he *meant;* I can only see what he *wrote.*